# Openapi 3 one single endpoint per operation

Tags: java, swagger, openapi

We have defined, for example, a path to create, read, modify and delete texts:

```
   /api/v1/applications/{applicationCode}/texts:
     get:
       tags:
       - Texts - Find texts
[...]
     post:
       tags:
       - Texts - Create text
[...]
     delete:
       tags:
       - Texts - Delete text
```

We have a tag for each endpoint, and thus it generates an interface for each one and thus we have each endpoint separated in a class (CreateTextEndpoint, FindTextEndpoint, etc). The problem is that the documentation in swagger is not very attractive, since it also separates and creates a section for each tag (as you can see in the image below).

[image]

Is it possible to have a class for each endpoint like we have, but grouping them in swagger?

Comment: Are the methods in the same order than in the controller class?

Comment: We have only one method per class, and that it is ok, but swagger is a mess because there too many sections, one by method

Comment: You seem to be misusing `tags`. Tags are used to create groups like that in Swagger UI. Maybe you meant to use those texts as operation `summary` or `description`?

Comment: Why not grouping methods by the class of the objects manipulated (here application?)

Comment: We use the tags, one for each method, because in this way, when openapi-generator creates the interfaces, it generates an interface for each endpoint, so we can create classes of the type CreateTextEndpoint, DeleteTextEndpoint, etc instead of a single class that contains all the methods, so we isolate the dependencies of each method and do not generate too large controllers